# elisp variable define. What's the function of slash in variable name like "defvar bh/organization-task-id"

Tags: emacs, lisp, org-mode

The function below is from [Org Mode - Organize Your Life In Plain Text!](http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html) It does not work in emacs-23.4-r1. But if i remove the bh/ prefix in bh/organization-task-id and change it to organization-task-id. It workd. I am don't know why. What's the function of the slash in the variable name and the function name? Thanks advance.

```
(defvar bh/organization-task-id "eb155a82-92b2-4f25-a3c6-0304591af2f9")

(defun bh/clock-in-organization-task-as-default ()
  (interactive)
  (org-with-point-at (org-id-find bh/organization-task-id 'marker)
    (org-clock-in '(16))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'bh/' stands for Bernt Hansen, the author of the function.

Since Elisp does not support namespaces, it is common practice to prefix your function and variable names with a common identifier in order to avoid conflict with names used in other modules. For example, all org-mode functions and variables start with `org-` or `ob-` (for org-babel).

I can't answer your question as to why does this fail on emacs-23.4.

Comment: He (BH) probaby rewrote those functions in his `.emacs` and since you are not (I presume) using his `.emacs` you don't have the `bh/*` functions around.  Using the normal `org-mode` versions therefore fixes the problem.

Comment: The function is failing probably because you don't have the proper org stuff installed. It looks like it needs `org-id-find` and two others.