# elisp: slash in identifiers

Tags: elisp, identifier, slash

What is the exact meaning of a slash in an identifier (function name, for instance)? Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720905/elisp-variable-define-whats-the-function-of-slash-in-variable-name-like-defva)

I guess it's some namespace substitute, but I'd like to know how to actually use it. A link to the docs will do; somehow I never managed to find it myself.

Comment: It's just a namespacing convention. It could just as easily be an underscore or a `~`. The entire name of the identifier includes the slash and Lisp doesn't interpret it in any special way.

Comment: @d11wtq why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: Somehow I can't find the place in elisp manual where identifier (what constitutes a correct symbol) syntax is defined.

Comment: Oddly enough the documentation of symbol types contains the info what you are looking for. http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Type.html#Symbol-Type

Answer (score 5):

Formally, it has no special meaning, just like - or underscore.  Some people use it instead of the dash as a "namespace separator", but Elisp has no namespaces other than by convention.